# Two variables being assigned at the same time

Tags: python, arrays

In python, if there are two variables being assigned a value in the same line, for example here

img_tensor, label = dataset[0]

Where dataset[0] is an array, what is actually going on? What does this do?

Comment: First index gets assigned to the first variable, the second index gets assigned to the second variable.

Comment: To expand on @NickParsons comment, if `dataset[0]` is something like `[1, 2]`, `img_tensor` will be `1` and `label` will be `2`.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two major cases while executing the line `img_tensor, label = dataset[0]`.

**Case 1:** If dataset[0] has a length of 2. As per comments it would assign the first index of `dataset[0]` to `img_tensor` and second index to `label`.

**Case 2:** If `len(dataset[0]) > 2` or `len(dataset[0]) < 2`. The line would produce `ValueError` yelling either "too many values to unpack" or "not enough values to unpack".

It can also result in a `TypeError` if `dataset[0]` is not an `iterable`

There might be other scenarios that are possible depending upon the type of `dataset[0]`.